# javascript: uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a javascript game, using Canvas. However, I got that error(below image) and background image is not shown. I suspect below 4 files, because other files didn't make any trouble. I guess the problem is related with game_state...how can I solve the problem??
I am agonizing for 2days:( plz, help me..

[error image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFTiT.png)

[error image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M9ST.png)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Lion Travel</title>

 <!--GameFramework-->
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/GameFramework.js"></script>
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/FrameCounter.js"></script>
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/InputSystem.js"></script>
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/SoundManager.js"></script>
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/GraphicObject.js"></script>
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/SpriteAnimation.js"></script>
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/ResourcePreLoader.js"></script>
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/DebugSystem.js"></script>
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/Timer.js"></script>
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/FrameSkipper.js"></script>
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/TransitionState.js"></script>

 <!--GameInit-->
 <script src="/.c9/gfw/gfw.js"></script>

 <!--Game Logic-->
 <script src="/.c9/RS_Title.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="GameCanvas" width="800" height="600">html5 canvas is not supported.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

gfw.js

```
function onGameInit() {
    document.title = "Lion Travel";

    GAME_FPS = 30;
    debugSystem.debugMode = true;

    resourcePreLoader.AddImage("/.c9/title_background.png");
    soundSystem.AddSound("/.c9/background.mp3", 1);

    after_loading_state = new TitleState();
    setInterval(gameLoop, 1000 / GAME_FPS); 
}

window.addEventListener("load", onGameInit, false);
```

RS_Title.js

```
function TitleState() 
{
    this.imgBackground = resourcePreLoader.GetImage("/.c9/title_background.png");
    soundSystem.PlayBackgroundMusic("/.c9/background.mp3");
    return this; 
}

TitleState.prototype.Init = function()
{
    soundSystem.PlayBackgroundMusic("/.c9/background.mp3");
};

TitleState.prototype.Render = function()
{
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById("GameCanvas");
    var Context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

    //drawing backgroundimage
    Context.drawImage(this.imgBackground, 0, 0);
};

TitleState.prototype.Update = function()
{

};
```

GameFramework.js

```
var GAME_FPS;
var game_state = after_loading_state;

function ChangeGameState(nextGameState)
{
    //checking essential function
    if(nextGameState.Init == undefined)
        return;

    if(nextGameState.Update == undefined)
        return;

    if(nextGameState.Render == undefined)
        return;

    game_state = nextGameState;

    game_state.Init();
}

function Update() 
{
    timerSystem.Update();

    game_state.Update();

    debugSystem.UseDebugMode();
}

function Render()
{
    //drawing
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById("GameCanvas");
    var Context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

    Context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    Context.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

    //game state
    game_state.Render();

    if(debugSystem.debugMode)
    {
        //showing fps
        Context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        Context.font = '15px Arial';
        Context.textBaseline = "top";
        Context.fillText("fps: "+ frameCounter.Lastfps, 10, 10);
    }
}

function gameLoop()
{
    Update();
    Render();

    frameCounter.countFrame();
}
```

Comment: In gfw.js you are declaring `after_loading_state = new TitleState();` but after_loading_state is not declared, is this something from the DOM or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are initializing `game_state` with the object `after_loading_state` even before `after_loading_state` is initialized(which is initialized only after the document is loaded). Due to this `game_state` remains `undefined`.

To fix this, change `var game_state = after_loading_state;` in GameFramework.js to `var game_state;`. And add `game_state = after_loading_state;` as the first line in `gameLoop` function. This way, the initialization of variables occur in the correct order.